# 127.0.0.7 show me Facebook homepage in Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, localhost

When I type `127.0.0.1` in browser it show to me the Facebook login page, but URL is still `127.0.0.1` not `https://www.facebook.com/`.
When I `nano /etc/hosts`:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
#
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Virtual directory support is disabled now. I cleaned dns cache with command:

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with /etc/hosts or DNS caching -- 127.0.0.1 is a raw IP address, so it bypasses all the name -> IP number stuff. What you're doing is connecting to a webserver (or proxy or something) running on your computer. What that is, and why it's serving (/proxying/whatevering) the facebook login page is something I cannot tell from the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can run netstat -tlpn (you may need to look at documentation to adjust these switches)

- **t** shows TCP ports
- **l** shows only ports that applications are listening on
- **p** shows the owning process
- **n** shows as numeric instead of resolving hostnames

From there, you can find the process owning the webserver (it should be running on port 80/443).

You can then get more info on the process using **ps aux | grep processName**. You'll want to run these commands from terminal. You may need to prefix them with **sudo** like "sudo netstat -tlpn" to let them run with root privileges so it shows all programs instead of just those running as your user. When you use sudo you will probably get a prompt box asking for your password.